# How to get the array of sheet ids in a folder with python

Tags: python, api, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

When I try to get the id array from the get.folder() call (by using folder = folder.sheets.id), I get the answer: "AttributeError: 'TypedList' object has no attribute 'id'" I'm not sure what function to call in python to get the array of sheet ids in the folder.

I am trying to do this with the python smartsheet sdk, but I am not sure exactly how to format it.

```
inc_list = ['all'] # you can add other parameters here, separated by a comma
 response = ss_client.Folders.copy_folder(
  folderID,                           # folder_id
  ss_client.models.ContainerDestination({
    'destination_id': destinationID,
    'destination_type': 'folder',
    'new_name': cellValue
  }),
include=inc_list
)

copiedFolderID = response.result.id

folder = ss_client.Folders.get_folder(
  copiedFolderID)       # folder_id 

newFolder = folder.sheets.id

print (newFolder)
```

Also thanks for helping answer my questions, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract list of attributes from list of objects in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739800/extract-list-of-attributes-from-list-of-objects-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`folder.sheets` is an array. The reason you're getting an error is because there is no `id` attribute at the array level - you need to look at the individual elements inside the array.

Take a look at the [API docs](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-folder) to get an example of what you'd receive.

```
sheet_ids = []
for sheet in folder.sheets
    sheet_ids.append(sheet.id)
print(sheet_ids)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, now I can get to work on creating the loop for editing the names of all the documents.

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of the sheetIds for sheets in a folder, your Python would look something like this.

```
my_folder = ss_client.Folders.get_folder(folder_id)

for sheet in my_folder.sheets:
    print(sheet.id)
```